# Does the JDK update itself?

Tags: java

Does the **JDK** *(Java Development Kit)* update itself?  I have noticed that I haven't gotten an update for **JDK** but only Java updates.

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: No, hence the need to manually check for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDK is used for writing java applications and is only updated manually.

The JRE is used for running java applications, such as jars and applets. Depending on the OS the JRE can be scheduled for automatic or manual update.

Some links with more details:

http://java.com/en/download/help/mac_java_update.xml

http://java.com/en/download/faq/expire_date.xml